# Unique vs Indexed

Tags: mysql

So i did some tests against Indexing 3 rows vs Unique key for those 3 rows.  The results surprised myself.

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    locationid INT(10)     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country    INT(2)      NOT NULL,
    state      INT(2)      NOT NULL,
    city       VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    INDEX(`country`),
    INDEX(`state`),
    INDEX(`city`)
);
```

vs

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    locationid INT(10)     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country    INT(2)      NOT NULL,
    state      INT(2)      NOT NULL,
    city       VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE(`country`, `state`, `city`)
);
```

So i tried to do some auto completing and i found the table with the 3 indices worked faster than the table with the single unique key.  The autocomplete sql looked like...

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT state, city 
              FROM locations
              WHERE city LIKE '$city%' and state=$state and country='US';";

    $mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

I noticed that the above code was running a bit slower so i went to mysql and just tried to type in and on average the single unique key would run about 5 times as slow...  Why?

Comment: try using more appropriate integer datatypes such as smallint unsigned and tinyint unsigned along with engine = innodb and declaring a composite primary key...

Comment: Testing query performance inside PHP won't give you the correct estimate of performance. Try running the queries in mysql command line/interface with *SQL_NO_CACHE*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is a unique [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).  Your second example contains three non-unique indexes.  That's a pretty big difference.

To see which index was actually getting used in those cases, run [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) on your query.

Bear in mind that the number of rows in the table, and the cardinality/selectivity of individual indexes will also determine whether or not indexes are used.

Answer (score 0):

This is an index on all 3 fields

```
 UNIQUE(`country`, `state`, `city`)
```

which is something else then 3 indexes on 3 fields:

```
INDEX(`country`),
INDEX(`state`),
INDEX(`city`)
```

(you're not using an index in the combined one I guess)